# Make Font Bigger

Tags: javascript, css

I cant figure out how to make the font bigger here. I've tried googling a couple things but none worked.

```
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Wrtie about me text here';
var speed = 50;
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted makes any attempt to control the font size. It's basic CSS. What have you tried?

Comment: try #demo {font-size:20px;} as css.

Comment: The code you posted here doesn't make sense.

Comment: Checkout https://jsfiddle.net/z8qehrf4/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change font size dynamically using JavaScript, you'd have to use [fontSize](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontsize.asp) property of HTML object [style](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp) property. Also your usage of setTimeout is incorrect - it will just write first letter of your text after 50 milliseconds. You should use setInterval or recursion. Your code could look something like:

```
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Wrtie about me text here';
var speed = 50;
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize = 12 + i + 'px';
    // write next letter of text after 50 ms
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
// initial function execution after 50 ms
setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
```